# ¿Cómo resuelvo un problema de índice fuera de rango?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Estoy construyendo un pequeño programa de gestión de almacén como parte de un pequeño curso de C# que estoy tomando, en el que apenas he construido la interfaz de login y otra en la que se gestionan los usuarios. Mi problema viene en el script de la gestión de usuarios, en ella agregué un DataGridView para plasmar las tablas de la base de datos donde se están almacenando los usuarios. Todo corre bien hasta que doy click en la tabla con los datos de la BD, entonces me salta un problema de manejo de excepción que dice:

> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Deber ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index.

Cuando se supone que debería desplegarme el contenido de la fila que selecciono en los mismo campos con los que se ingresaría un nuevo usuario y posteriormente editarlo o borrarlo. El siguiente es el código del script correspondiente a dicha interfaz. He retirado la liga del data source de la BD.
Cabe mencionar que para el diseño de la interfaz utilicé las herramientas de diseño de Bunifu.

### También dejo link para el repositorio de GitHub de este proyecto para quien guste descargarlo, correrlo en su PC, y quizás así pueda entenderme mejor y ayudarme.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ControlAlmacenMSS
{
    public partial class GestionUsuarios : Form
    {        
        public GestionUsuarios()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Cambiar conexión a la ubicación del archivo Sql dependiendo de la PC que se está usando
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0044:Agregar modificador de solo lectura", Justification = "<pendiente>")]
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"");

        private void LabelCerrarGest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        void  Rellenar()
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Open();
                string MiConsulta = "select * from GestionUsuarios";
                SqlDataAdapter adaptadorDatos = new SqlDataAdapter(MiConsulta, Con);
                SqlCommandBuilder cmdConstructor = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptadorDatos);
                var conjuntoDatos = new DataSet();
                adaptadorDatos.Fill(conjuntoDatos);
                DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.DataSource = conjuntoDatos.Tables[0];
                Con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        private void BtnAgregarGest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Open();
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into GestionUsuarios values('"+BunMatTbNombreGest.Text
                    +"','"+BunMatTbUsuarioGest.Text
                    +"','"+BunMatTbContraGest.Text
                    +"','"+BunMatTbMailGest.Text
                    +"','"+BunMatTbTelGest.Text+"')",Con); 
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("USUARIO AGREGADO");
                Con.Close();
                Rellenar();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        private void GestionUsuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rellenar();
        }

        private void BtnEditarGest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Open();
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("update GestionUsuarios set Nombre='"+BunMatTbNombreGest.Text
                    +"',Usuario='"+BunMatTbUsuarioGest.Text
                    +"',Contraseña='"+BunMatTbContraGest.Text
                    +"',Email='"+BunMatTbMailGest.Text
                    +"' where Teléfono='"+BunMatTbTelGest.Text 
                    +"'", Con);
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("USUARIO ACTUALIZADO");
                Con.Close();
                Rellenar();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnBorrarGest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(BunMatTbTelGest.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INGRESA EL NÚMERO DE TELÉFONO DEL USUARIO");
            }
            else
            {
                Con.Open();
                string miConsulta = "delete from GestionUsuarios where Contraseña = '"+BunMatTbTelGest+"';";
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(miConsulta, Con);
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("USUARIO BORRADO");
                Con.Close();
                Rellenar();
            }
        }
        // En este método se encuentra el "error" mencionado
        private void DataGridViewGestionUsuarios_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Estas líneas se comentan para que dicho error no aparezca al correr el programa.
            BunMatTbNombreGest.Text = DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            BunMatTbUsuarioGest.Text = DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            BunMatTbContraGest.Text = DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            BunMatTbMailGest.Text = DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            BunMatTbTelGest.Text = DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Agredeceré toda la ayuda y correcciones que me puedan hacer.

Comment: Deja ver si me entiendes, c# tiene todos sus errores codificados con un número ej        cs1234, busca ese número y publicarlo aquí para entender mejor

Comment: Yo considero que el error podria estar aqui, `SelectedRows[0]`, por que accedes directamente al primer registro de tu array, sin validar si tiene algo, puedes agregar una validación de que SelectedRows sea mayor a cero al entrar al evento.

Comment: La verdad es que no veo ningún código de error, simplemente salta un cuadro de diálogo con el error mencionado y en detalles dice sobre cómo activar la depuración JIT para el manejo de excepciones.

Comment: El detalle es que siempre hay datos en la tabla, por lo menos una fila de la tabla tiene datos en todas las columnas.

Comment: @IvanTenryu: en su pregunta dice: `Cuando se supone que debería desplegarme el contenido de la fila que selecciono en los mismo campos con los que se ingresaría un nuevo usuario y posteriormente editarlo o borrarlo` = mire qué valores tiene `conjuntoDatos.Tables[0];` en `DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.DataSource = conjuntoDatos.Tables[0];` (*mire las columnas y filas*). Aquí está el error. Revise el contenido de `conjuntoDatos.Tables[0];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema se encuentra aqui:

SelectedRows[0] --> si la consulta no tiene datos para retornar, se cae.
Cells[4] --> si el select de la tabla tiene solo 4 campos , como los indices van de 0 a 4 , en el 4 se cae.

```
DataGridViewGestionUsuarios.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: En la tabla hay cinco columnas con información en tres filas. Y se supone que siempre habrá por lo menos una fila con datos llenando las cinco columnas.